# linux pgrep by excluding specific user

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm using `pgrep` command on a shell script to monitor some java application. But there is a continues service from java which is giving problem on my code. That process belongs to another user. So, is there any way to exclude the process from specific user while using grep?

The following is the script line I'm currently using:

```
pgrep java
```

I need to exclude the processes of a specific user. Please help me to modify this script and get the output. Note that I'm using Solaris.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) with `-u` or `-U` option:

```
-u euid,...
    Only match processes whose effective user ID is listed. Either the 
    numerical or symbolical value may be used.
-U uid,...
    Only match processes whose real user ID is listed. Either the numerical 
    or symbolical value may be used.
```

So, try:

```
pgrep -u youruser java
```

will list all processes called java and owned by youruser.

If you want to exclude a user, you can:

```
grep -vxf <(pgrep -u exclude_user java) <(pgrep java)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want it to lost with the user not in the list. For example there is a user call "noaccess". So i want to remove the process from "noaccess" user from the output list. How can i apply not condition for the attribute "-u" here?

Comment: @guru: see my updated.

Comment: i got following error: # grep -vxf <(pgrep -u noaccess java) <(pgrep java)
syntax error: `(' unexpected

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: I think it should be like follows {pgrep java | grep -v `pgrep -u exclude_user java`}. Because this is working. Thank you. Actually I guess the answer from your post.